# Java - Unmappable character for encoding Cp1252

Tags: java, command-prompt, notepad

I'm working on this extra project, and I just took a break for a couple of days. I come back and try to debug a problem that was occurring and this appears. [image]

The compiler reports 100 errors (three types - unmappable character for encoding Cp1252, illegal escape character, illegal character: '\u####' (See screenshot for examples of what # can represent), the google search I've done leads me to believe that this is "unicode")

This error appears for 3/4 of my source files when I try to javac them (tested each file individually)

Being rather new to java (I'm in Computer Science 120 at highschool...) I haven't the slightest clue what to do about this error.

Google search talks about special characters (such as trade-mark characters). Of which there is no such thing in my code any wheres, as well as encoding.

While I don't understand really understand this encoding thing, from what I've read in the google searches, it sounds like each operating system uses a default encoding format and JVM will use the set format. However, I've javac the program (and several other programs) several times, furthermore the code hasn't changed for roughly a week (due another issue I've been having).

Further after commenting out everything related to my other issue, this problem still appears, despite that I know my program should be javac-ing fine with the code I've commented out.

With no changes for the past week, I haven't the slightest clue what could be possibly causing this, noting this error has not appeared for me before.

As for my question... What's happening? How do I fix this?
I'm using -

Windows 7

Java 8

Notepad

Command-Prompt

Comment: `Element.java` seems to be a JAR file. You can try to extract it as `jar xvf Element.java`.

Comment: Hmmm, that's extremely odd. I do use a jar file, but this jar file is created by me to hold 3/4 source files, so I can have my html file (I'm using an applet to run this program) load in that jar file through the archive attribute...

Comment: Ah I think I know what happened now, after my two-day break I took a couple minutes reviewing the command prompt commands, specificly the jar command. I remember making a mistake and forgetting to add the jar name... Which must have been the Element.java file. So I think I've over-written my Element.java file, luckily there was not much code in there. Should take like 2minutes to recode. Thanks for the help!